# How to code this pattern using the while loop and for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I am supposed to code this pattern:

```
[1]
[0][0]    
[1][1][1]  
[0][0][0][0] 
[1][1][1][1][1]  
[0][0][0][0][0][0]
[1][1][1][1][1][1][1]          
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]         
[1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1]
```

However, i am only able to give a output like this:

```
[1]    
[0][0]
[1][1][1] 
[0][0][0][0] 
[1][1][1][1][1]    
[0][0][0][0][0][0]     
[1][1][1][1][1][1][1]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1] 
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
```

this is my current code:

```
a = '[1]'
b = '[0][0]'

for c in range(1,10,2):
    print(a)
    a = a + '[1][1]'
    print(b)
    b = b + '[0][0]'
```

Please help! I am supposed to the pattern with a while loop and for loop. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing both `a` and `b` in every iteration, so naturally you can't get odd number of lines in your output.

Instead, use a normal range iterator of 9 and alternate between printing and appending to `a` and `b` depending on the counter's remainder of 2.

```
a = '[1]'
b = '[0][0]'

for c in range(9):
    if c % 2 == 0:
        print(a)
        a = a + '[1][1]'
    else:
        print(b)
        b = b + '[0][0]'
```

This outputs:

```
[1]
[0][0]
[1][1][1]
[0][0][0][0]
[1][1][1][1][1]
[0][0][0][0][0][0]
[1][1][1][1][1][1][1]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried doing it in a while loop but am unable to get the output. Isit possible if you told me how to do it in a while loop too? Much appreciated!